# Multiple regex patterns in Clojure?

Tags: regex, clojure

I'm trying to make my code more readable but still try have as much sense as possible, I would like to test a string vs a few regex patterns.

```
( re-find #"(?i)(^select .* from .*)|(^delete from me)" c))
```

And I would like to split this into 2 separate patterns but maybe use one test? is there anything that would test a set of patterns vs 1 string?

Thanks!

Comment: There's all kinds of constructs to do multiple tests. There isn't one "combine these regexps" function because there's too much variation. What do you want the result to be? For example, do you want results of each regexp? Each regexp that matches? The first regexp that matches?

Comment: Good point, missed it, updated my post. Only looking for a match/no match flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(def patterns [#"(?i)^select .* from .*" #"(?i)^delete from me"])

(when (some #(re-find % "your test string") patterns)
 ...)
```

[clojure.core/some](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/some)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!
Just one some question: can I have an "else" or "default" for the when? i.e. can I somehow return false instead of the nil?

Comment: `nil` is a falsy value. You don't have to use `when`. `if` has an else form. `(if test true-form else-form)`